# How to output and display Unicode in Groovy Console (GroovyStarter) and GGTS / Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, unicode, groovy, groovy-console

I would like to output [floral formulae](http://www.academia.edu/1175371/Floral_formulae_updated_for_routine_inclusion_in_formal_taxonomic_descriptions) by my DSL in [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org), so I need some special symbols such as [female sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2640/index.htm) and [Superscripts and Subscripts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf).

The question is about the Eclipse IDE ([Groovy/Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts) Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE to develop a grails project) and Groovy console (GroovyStarter)

given this sample groovy statement:

`println '♀ Ca\u2075'`

I get the expected output in terminal if I run the program from the terminal:

```
$ groovy Testformula.groovy   
♀ Ca⁵
```

The same is OK if I run it from the [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts) as a *Java application* but if I eighter run it as a *Groovy script* or in the *Groovy console* (Groovy starter) I get question mark instead of unicode symbols:

```
groovy> package org.rondakit.test 
groovy> class Testformula { 
groovy>     static void main(def args) { 
groovy>         println '\u2640' 
groovy>         println '♀ Ca\u2075' 
groovy>     } 
groovy> }
```

I get the nasty result:

```
?
? Ca?
```

**Question**: is it possible to configure *GroovyStarter* or the *Groovy Console* on GGTS to display unicode symbols?

Comment: Groovy Version: 2.0.5 JVM: 1.7.0_06 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X $ Grails version: 2.1.1 –

Comment: It works fine in my box (ubuntu 12.04) under GGTS using "Run as..." either Groovy Console or Groovy Script. Are you sure there isn't any configuration in your ggts?

Comment: @Will P: your comment suggested me to try in another box: then I try on a Windows 7 x64 the same exercise on Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 
Version: 3.1.0.M1 Build Id: 201209120902 and I get results similar to those previously seen on Mac OSX. 1) "Run as" "Java Application" in OK; 2) "Run as" "Groovy script" give bad output: ? â™€ Ca?; 3)  "Run As" "Grovy Console" open the GroovyConsole 1.8.6 but the output was bad ?
? Ca?

Comment: @WillP +1: great tip! I investigate my ggts settings with these findings: in "Preferences"->"Workspace" I suspected the "Text File Encoding" set on defalt "Cp1252" then I try to change this setting to "Other: UTF-8" and this solves both problems! if you want post your answer I will be happy to accept ut as a solution.

Comment: On the Mac OSX the GGTS default setting of "Text file Encoding" was "US-ASCII" this might explain the small difference ( "? ? Ca?" Vs. "? â™€ Ca?" ) anyway by settings "UTF-8" also solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine in my box (ubuntu 12.04) under GGTS using "Run as..." either Groovy Console or Groovy Script. You may want to check configuration in your ggts.

Windows by default runs on cp1252 encoding (we had some troubles with source on wrong encoding in some projects this year). Linux by default is utf-8. I'm not sure about OS X

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution for groovyConsole, You need to put "export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to environment variable

Comment: I've already solved as you can read in the comments, but I appreciate your advice, +1 thank you.